# Как узнать измененый номер перетаскиваемого элимента Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

использую jqueryui sortable вот код

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default wells" data-id="59" data-cat="1">
        Для него
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default wells" data-id="64" data-cat="1" style="">
       Распродажа
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default wells" data-id="57" data-cat="1">
        Для нее
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default wells" data-id="62" data-cat="1">
       Для дома
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove del"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

вот таким кодом подключаю

```
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    stop: console.log(ui)
});
```

получаю объект но вот где в нем найти номер позиции элимента не знаю не позиционирование элимента left, top, а имено номер позиции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответов куча на твой вопрос, постарайся погуглить на инглише в следующий раз:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979643/jquery-ui-sortable-position
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601827/jquery-ui-sortable-how-to-determine-current-location-and-new-location-in-update
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467820/jquery-sortable-get-index-before-and-after-sorting